# Bean created by spring are used by all calls. what if in any one call i updated some context will that be available to any other call to spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring created a bean if I change a local variable of that class. forex - I change a variable value.
will that new value be available for any new thread or call to spring application api.

Comment: By default Spring beans are singleton means there will be only one instance of a class present in the application context.

Comment: So the answer is yes.

Comment: @Karthikeyan what if i have data member in that bean and i changed that data memeber in one of the api call.
will that be reflected to other api calls

Comment: @Kakarot Yes, whatever you have at the class level in spring beans will act as an application-level global variable. You must be cautious with this.

Answer (score 1):

Spring beans are created for the purpose of dependency injection. That means, you don't pass these bean objects as parameters nor do you change these beans as they are singleton in nature. These beans are injected in corresponding classes where their properties and methods could be used.

And, if you are changing these beans in some method, then the entire fundamental of making beans for the purpose of dependency injection will be breached.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Also, if it is not what you asked, can you please share some codeblock where the things could be more clear?